# Preencher dados automáticos - JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Preciso fazer com que os meus inputs sejam preenchidos automáticos, após seleção da combo. Já fiz o método para percorrer o banco de dados e recuperar as informações necessárias, porém não preenche... Alguém pode me ajudar?
Creio eu que devido ao update do ajax, mas não sei como fazer atualizar o formulário...

index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="formGeral" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid id="panelDados" columns="4" cellpadding="8">
        <p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Projeto:" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{usuarioBean.projeto.codigo}"
            required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Projeto' é obrigatório.">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o projeto" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{projetoBean.projetos}" var="projeto"
                itemLabel="#{projeto.projeto}" itemValue="#{projeto.codigo}" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{usuarioBean.popularProjeto}"
                update=":formGeral" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Superior Imediato:" />
        <p:inputText id="superiorImediato"
            value="#{usuarioBean.recebeSuperior}" />
        <p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Tipo projeto:" />
        <p:inputText id="tipoProjeto"
            value="#{usuarioBean.recebeTipoProjeto}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

método para recuperar os dados:

```
public void popularProjeto() {
    try {
        if (projeto != null) {
            Projeto recebeProjeto = projetoDAO.buscarPorCodigo(projeto.getCodigo());
            recebeSuperior = recebeProjeto.getProjeto();
            recebeTipoProjeto = recebeProjeto.getTipo();

            System.out.println(recebeSuperior);
            System.out.println(recebeTipoProjeto);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, o atributo para renderizar é o render do f:ajax

```
...
<f:ajax listener="#{usuarioBean.popularProjeto}" render="formGeral" />
...
```

**Veja mais em:**
http://jamacedo.com/2010/04/aprenda-a-utilizar-o-ajax-nativo-do-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Acredito que o que o usuário quer, seja dar um update nos componentes ao selecionar um valor no combo, então seria dar um `update`, concorda?
Também há um outro detalhe, é usado `Primefaces` pelo visto

Comment: Olá Macario1983, seria sim `update` se a tag utilizada fosse a `<p:ajax>` mas a tag utilizada no exemplo é a `<f:ajax>` que não possui o atributo `update`.

Comment: você esta correto